# ネストしたコレクションの処理をforループからjava8 streamへ置き換える

Tags: java, java8, stream

1対多の親子関係があるようなインスタンスのリスト処理を、従来はネストした`for`文で行っていました。

```
class Parent {
    List <Child> children;

    List <Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}

class Child {
}
```

```
List <Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
// Parent, Child 生成...

for (Parent p : parents) {
    for (Child c : p.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(c); // c を使った処理
    }
}
```

上記`for`文を、`Stream`を使用したものに置き換えたいと考えています。
自分が思いついたものとしては次の2パターンが有るのですが、実行結果はどちらも変わらないように思われました。
実際には途中の処理順やパフォーマンス等、何か差異があるでしょうか。

また、`Stream`の書き方としてより適切なのはどちら(あるいはどちらでもない)か、というのも知りたいです。
(バラせるところはバラしたほうが良い、つまりパターン1の方が良いのかな、と漠然と考えているのですが…)

```
// パターン1
parents.stream().map(Parent::getChildren).flatMap(List::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);

// パターン2
parents.stream().flatMap(p -> p.getChildren().stream())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: FYI: メソッド参照とラムダ式の違いに関する記事を以前に見たことがありました。既にご存知でしたらすみません。 http://appresso.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/11/04/132543

Comment: ありがとうございます。そこまでシビアに考えていたわけでは無かったので、書かれているような点は今回考慮の外でした。完全に等価というわけではない、ということは頭の片隅に置いておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 実際には途中の処理順やパフォーマンス等、何か差異があるでしょうか。

- 逐次(sequential)ストリームとなっているため、両パターンとも処理順序は同一です。
- （有意差はないと予想しますが、）パフォーマンス比較は実環境にて計測してください。

> Streamの書き方としてより適切なのはどちら(あるいはどちらでもない)か、というのも知りたいです。

正解のない問いだと思いますが、個人的には パターン2 の方が好ましいと考えます。

- パターン1: `.map(Parent::getChildren).flatMap(List::stream)`
- パターン2: `.flatMap(p -> p.getChildren().stream())`

論理的には「子Listのflatten処理」でひとかたまりの操作ですから、パターン1のように外側ストリームのメソッドチェインで分断してしまうより、パターン2のように一度のflatMap操作で変換する方が意図をより直接的にコード化しているという考え方です。

Comment: `Parent::getChildren` という書き方が新しく出来るようになったのだから、使えるところではそのように書くのが正しい、という先入観があったようです。パターン1は、`for`ループで例えるなら、1回のループで済むことを無駄に処理を分断して2回ループを回しているイメージだと理解しました。

Answer (score 0):

どちらでもいいのではないでしょうか？
こういう書き方もあります。

```
parents.stream()
    .forEach(p -> p.children.stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Parentが変わる前後で何か処理をしたい場合はこの書き方がいいですね。